# xsl:fo how to check new page appears and special ouput

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Hi guys my issue: I have a table with 2 colums and if a new page appears in the left column should be displayed a text like "continue page".
What is the best way to implement it and how :)

Here a picture it should look like :

First Page:
[image]
Second Page (If the table goes over 2 Sites):

[image]

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: This is done thanks to `<fo:marker>` and `<fo:retrieve-table-marker>`, please see http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-table-marker.

Comment: do know if saxon processor supports this ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Saxon. Saxon is an XSL-T processor. It it the rendering engine (e.g. FOP, Antenna House, RenderX, ...) producing the PDF that will take use `<fo:marker>`. For me, they are able to process it correctly.

Comment: I think I need to see a bit more of the markup. It's not clear whether you mean you have a two column document with a table or whether you have a single column document with a two column table. And whether the repeated heading is a heading or only in the left column. Please show a picture (at least) of your desired output.

Comment: I have added 2 Pictures ;)

Comment: On the right column their is a very long text and on the left site their should been output the "continue" text if it goies on a new site

Comment: Is there nothing in the left column? Just the word "continue"? Or? That picture is not clear at all. Why not use something like Word to mockup what you want and use that picture.

Comment: so changed the picture again ;)

Comment: has nobody a idea to manage this problem? Or is this immpossible with XSLT(FO) ?